# win2008 r2 enterprise "Message Queuing" "Access is denied" "The list of messages cannot be retrieved"

Tags: windows-server-2008, msmq, windows, message-queuing

on my win7, I run compmgmt.msc and drill to a private queue
folder ...  when I click "Queue messages" or "Journal messages",
I either see the messages, or "There are no items to show in this view".

BUT, on win2008 R2 Enterprise, I run compmgmt.msc and drill to a private queue
folder ...  when I click "Queue messages" or "Journal messages",
I see "There are no items to show in this view" which AFAIK
is correct BUT I get this unwanted dialog:

```
Message Queuing        x  
------------------------  
(X) The list of messages cannot be retrieved.  
    Error:  Access is denied.  
                 [[  OK  ]]
```

On both computers, I'm a member of local Administrators.

I'm concerned as a developer because I'm very soon
going to be testing WCF/MSMQ software that works
on my Win7 laptop.

How to I get past this denied access problem?

thnx / g.

Comment: update:  I am able to create new message queues; the new queues behave properly for me.  The behaviour of the queues reported in my question has not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server is a domain server; it's administrator had made me a local administrator.

i'm not sure why, but i had less power that the domain administrator account.

i'm sure Microsoft has a rational for this but imho a local admin should have the same rights within the box as the domain admins when it comes to managing things that pertain to that box such as local resources like message queues.

i can envision scenarios in very large organizations where a corporation does not want to extend a local admins' power beyond a specific server while at the same time giving that admin responsibility over the local server.

regardless of my opinions, the problem was resolved when the domain admin also made me a member of the domain admins.

BTW, i can not remember for sure, but íf my memory is correct, the domain admin had a similar problem with accessing queues i created; that also seems strange in that a domain admin is more powerful than a local admin. note: this was a while ago, so my memory could be wrong.

@John Breakwell ... thank you for your participation.  much appreciated.  B-)

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2012/03/msmqsecurity-descriptor-cannot-be-set.html

Take OWNERSHIP
Add permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like someone changed the queue permissions in the past. Queues have standard NT security so just change the permissions on the old queues. You may need to take ownership if the previous owner account no longer exists.

Cheers
John Breakwell